# Gibbs sampling in the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, gibbs, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

For an inference problem using a Dirichlet Process prior, one can derive a "basic" Gibbs sampling scheme, where we have a conditional for any parameter $\theta_i$ given the samples $x_i$ and all the other parameters:

$$ \theta_i|\theta_{-i},x_1,...,x_n $$

Improvements can be made to this by introducing indicator variables. For the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process (HDP), in all the papers I have seen, the Gibbs samplers given are the version with indicator variables - however I am looking for the HDP "basic" Gibbs sampler equations like the DP one above, so without indicators, just with parameters and samples. Does anyone know of a reference where these are given (and ideally with a derivation)?

Comment: Equation 8 on page 6 of this paper (https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/teh-jordan-bnp.pdf) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Eric Mittman - thanks, but that equation only conditions on parameters, I am seeking the Gibbs conditionals given both parameters and samples (without the use of indicator variables).

Comment: Something like 3.2-3.4 from here: http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/DirichletProc/NealDirichletJCGS2000.pdf ?

Comment: @Eric Mittman - thanks, but those are the "basic" inference eqns for the DP that I quoted above. I need the same for the HDP.

Comment: Have you read the main reference for this - if yes, what is not clear: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/hdp.pdf